# Speed of Gravity

Tags: gravity

Is the speed of gravity instant? By the speed of gravity, I'm not talking about acceleration.

What I mean is something like this:
If I take a vacuum, for example, and put in two objects of the same size, shape, and mass, exactly 1 light year apart. In this vacum, no other objects exist anywhere. Therefore, these two objects will have gravity towards each other. How long will it take before the force of gravity to *start* acting? One year, (as it's the speed of light) or instantly?

Under both conditions, I have question expanding on them.

If it is instant, then could we theoretically have a machine sensitive enough to pick up gravity of objects outside of our observable universe?

If it's not, then what would happen if an object with high enough gravity (Like super-super-super massive black hole) were to suddenly enter our observable universe. Then would we be hugely affected? What would happen?

Comment: This question might be better suited to Physics SE.

Comment: belongs to Physics.SE.........

Comment: ...and I believe for *actual, factual* answer we'll have to wait until [eLISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolved_Laser_Interferometer_Space_Antenna) sends its results.

Comment: Also, why a supermassive black hole? Why not keep it simple and use the classic Gedankenexperiment where our sun suddenly disappears?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered [several times on Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22speed+of+gravity%22) before, so I can't migrate there only to be closed as a duplicate. I personally prefer [this thread](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7041/21740), if that helps. But agreed, this is off-topic here as per our [About] (see the _Don't ask_ section), if you don't ask specifically about space based gravimetry and gravitational waves missions like e.g. LISA Pathfinder that was just launched in Dec. 2015, or planned eLISA. Please don't cross-post.

Comment: @Hennes -- That is not a good question. You are in essence asking "what do the (known) laws of physics say will happen when those laws are violated?" Mass is a conserved quantity in Newtonian mechanics, so the question doesn't make sense from a Newtonian perspective. Mass-energy is locally conserved in general relativity, so the question doesn't make sense from a relativistic perspective, either. What make make sense is to ask what would happen if the Sun exploded. But that too has already been answered at physics.SE.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Supposedly (I still have to find an authoritative source) energy-derived mass is not a gravitational mass. So if one were to create or destroy a significant amount of matter (e.g. annihilate a massive amount of antimatter with equal mass of matter) the *gravitational mass* will change.

Comment: @SF. - See, for example, these questions at physics.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45882/what-kind-of-energy-gravitates-and-why, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90507/do-electromagnetic-fields-gravitate, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/does-a-photon-exert-a-gravitational-pull, and also this wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%2Denergy_tensor.

Comment: That spacecraft are navigated successfully to other planets and their satellites with great precision is good experimental verification that gravity does indeed moves at the speed of light just like special relativity says it does.